# Can I access delayed value in SystemVerilog assertion

Tags: fpga, system-verilog, verification, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I want to use an old value of a signal in a SystemVerilog assertion.

This is what I am currently doing

```
logic [ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] old_address [1:0];

always_ff@(posedge rdclock) begin
   old_address[0] <= rdaddress;
   old_address[1] <= old_address[0];
end

property FooBar;
   @(posedge rdclock) rden |-> ##2 q == mem[old_address[1]];
endproperty

Baz: assert property (FooBar);
```

Is this how is should be done, or can I somehow use an old version of `rdaddress` directly in the assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$past(...)` system task. Using `$past(rdaddress)` will return the value of `rdaddress` that was sampled in the previous cycle. You can specify how many cycle in the past to go with the second argument. In your case, calling `$past(rdaddress, 2)` will return the value of `rdaddress` 2 cycles before.